# Pipe to get one line output of command

Tags: bash, pipe, ffmpeg, fsarchiver

There are a few commands that print some status lines in the console when they are doing something (ffmpeg or fsarchiver).

```
-[00][  0%][DIR     ] /boot/grub/fonts
-[00][  0%][REGFILE ] /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2
-[00][  0%][REGFILEM] /boot/grub/grubenv
-[00][  0%][REGFILEM] /boot/grub/grub.cfg
-[00][  0%][REGFILE ] /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
```

Now i want to build a script that makes use of these commands but the output will purge away the script messages very fast.
I know that there are other commands like the new apt or wget that show progress in one line that continously updates.

I already played a little with such one line status lines in my script finding out that instead of newlines \n i need to place carriage returns \r which totally makes sense.

Then i tried to do the same with the commands (ffmpeg or fsarchiver) piping the ouput to `tr "\n" "\r"` . But i found out that this does not change something.

Is there any way to get a one line status line out of such commands?

Regards

Comment: I need a more precise description of the problem (intended vs. seen output) in order to help you. And you should provide a way to generate suitable test output with generally available software.

Comment: Example command to generate output: `while true; do date; sleep 1; done`

After each second the last line should be replaced with the next in sequence

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you basically answered your own question. When you pipe output to `tr`, did you pipe BOTH `stdout` AND `stderr`?

Comment: That improved the situation a bit but if the previous line is longer than the next a part of the older line is not cleared

Comment: You can use terminal escape sequences to clear the line. For example, `echo -e "\033[2K"` should clear the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

It is a buffering problem:

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done | stdbuf --output=0 tr '\n' '\r'
```

Comment: That works but if the command that is run has different output lengths than a shorter line won't override the whole previous line.